# dynamically select an excel element

Tags: excel-formula

guys,

I want to select an element from a column based on column name. This column changes its place time to time and that's why I want to achieve this dynamically. I couldn't post an image here so I'll try my best to explain it in words.

In the excel sheet I'm trying to select an element located at B2 dynamically based on column name of B2. For sake of simplicity lets say the column name of B is column2.  Since my column2 would not always be on B place I want to select that dynamically.I also want this to achieve without VBA code if possible.

Really look forward for your help. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something `INDEX` & `MATCH` would solve.  What have you tried?  Where does the column change its place to - same sheet, same workbook, same range?  _select an element located at B2 dynamically based on column name of B2_ - not sure what this is getting at.  Surely the column name of `B2` is column `B`?

Comment: If you are trying to get some range dynamically then you can use INDIRECT function, for eg: if cell B2 is a range 'A2:A2000' and you need to get sum of the range, then you can use =SUM(INDIRECT(B2)). INDIRECT returns a range based on the reference text.

Comment: So I've used MATCH function to find the index of the column from column row but then I don't know how to use INDEX because this function asks for lookup array and my lookup array [column B] would change its place. By the way, the column would change its place in the same sheet.

There is a header row in my excel sheet. So the first row holds column names for an example Age, DOB, Address.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to use INDEX function where I can pass the lookup array [Desired Dynamic Column] and get the value at certain index.

Comment: @Anees Hameed, So I used INDIRECT function within my INDEX function following way. My B2 cell holds a range A2:A6 and I want to get the third element in the range A2:A6. So I used INDEX(INDIRECT(B2), 3, 0) but that returns #REF!.

Comment: Could you layout some sample data in your question please.  What range does your data table cover?  What value is held in `B2`? Would the `B2` value be found in the data table, or is it the name of a column header in the data table?  Is it an actual data table - you can reference the headers as `=Table1[#Headers]` or just a range of cells and the headers would be referenced as `=Sheet1!A1:C1`?

Answer (score 0):

Below formula may help you in this,
Explanation:
MATCH will return the column position of "DOB", if DOB is in column C, MATCH will be returning 3.
ADDRESS will the row 1 address of column C, $C$1 hence; which is a text in fact.
Pass this text to INDIRECT function so that it gets converted to range. Now INDIRECT function will be pointing to cell C1.
Use cell C1 as reference and return 3 item in that colum.

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("DOB",1:1,0))),3,0)
```

Formula is expecting row 1:1 as header. You can pass B2 in place of "DOB".